# How to get string between bracket from multiple files name?

Tags: php

Suppose I have 5 files in a folder. And the file names are like below

- sdfsf (email_a@domain.com) - 2015-12-05 0508.eml
- sdfsdf sd Glitch' (email_b@domain.com) - 2015-12-30 0602.eml
- not so easy(email_c@domain.com) - 2015-12-31 1719.eml
- habi jabi (email_d@domain.com) - 2016-01-06 0513.eml
- you should (email_e@domain.com) - 2015-12-27 1227.eml

Now I want to get the string between the "()" brackets from the file names and want to save them in a text file.

So the output will be saved in a text file like below

```
email_a@domain.com
email_b@domain.com
email_c@domain.com
email_d@domain.com
email_e@domain.com
```

I've tried this code

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("./ABC/*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: as a regex, `\((.*)\)` ? https://regex101.com/r/gK1yK1/1

Answer (score 1):

Best done with regular expressions as Andrew noted.

```
   $files = scandir('folder/');
   foreach($files as $file) {
     preg_match("/(?:\\((.*)\\))/", $file, $matches); # Or "/\((.*)\)/" by Andrew
     var_dump($matches);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use preg_match to solve this with regular expression. So in this case use the following code:

```
preg_match('/\(.*\)/', $filename, $matches);
$new_file_name = substr($matches[0],1,strlen($matches[0])-2); //skip the openning and closing parenthesis
```

now $new_file_name will only contains the data in between parenthesis.

Hope it helps